# error launching a robotframework script [OSERROR 216] error

Tags: robotframework

I have a problem when launching my robotframework file. This is an [OSERROR 216] error. The browser didn't even open. The browser didn't even open.
the error message is

> OSError: [WinError 216] This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows currently running. Check your computer's system information, then contact the software editor.
> the software editor

My robotframework script is supposed to open a browser and then close it

Comment: Is your question something like "why is <problem> happening and how can I get <desired behaviour>?" If so, please [edit] to say so and fill in those blanks.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or errors. They aren't searchable and the visually impaired might not be able to see it at all. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the code and errors.